# Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported. What is causing it?

Tags: java, docker, maven, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

My merge commit failed a pipeline due to this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project api-gateway-v2: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
```

What does it mean? I do indeed use Java 17 in that project

```xml
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

Should I upgrade the maven-compiler-plugin version? Should I change something here:

```xml
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I guess something happens in the CI/CD server (we use GitLab CI)? Is my Dockerfile wrong or something?

```
FROM maven:3.8.4-openjdk-17-slim as builder
WORKDIR /src
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B
COPY ./src ./src
RUN mvn package -DskipTests


FROM alpine:3.15.3
RUN apk --no-cache add openjdk17-jre
COPY ./afinny.p12 ./afinny.p12
COPY --from=builder /src/target/*-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Googling the error message didn't help

Notice it's "17 not supported", not "11 not supported" so it's not a duplicate

## UPD

Since I can't post it as an asnwer, it seems it was due to

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 16.4.1 (d89a789a)[0;m
[0K  on shared-runner-04 Bf1nZaET, system ID: s_83ee1dfed7fd[0;m
section_start:1703171474:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image maven:3.8.4-jdk-11-slim ...[0;m
```

It's raw pipeline logs. I guess, Docker executor should use the same Java version or something? Anyway, I showed it to our devops guy, he upgraded the executor's image version, and now <s>it works</s> we hit DockerHub's pull limit

Comment: My assumption is that you are using a JDK lower than JDK17... maybe JDK11 ? What does `mvn --version` show?

Comment: You're running with a Java version < 17 which thus doesn't even know 17 exists.

Comment: 'java -version' Run this command on cmd (windows) and check which version of java is active currently. You can also have multiple versions installed, but default is pointing to lower java version.

Comment: @khmarbaise I only have Java 17 locally, it's all fine. But something happens in the CI/CD server, I guess. Are my Dockerfiles wrong or something?